# How to run task from .vscode/tasks.json in Visual Studio (2019 or later)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2019

I have several tasks in .vscode/tasks.json. This tasks I can run in Visual Studio Code via Command Pallete (CTRL+Shift+P). Is there any way to run tasks form .vscode/tasks.json in Visual Studio 2019 (or later)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **Task Runner Explorer** window in VS 2019 and several extensions for it, but there is no guarantee it can run your specific tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I did not find any extensions for the VS 2019 Task Runner Explorer window. It would be great if you share a link to it.

Comment: @Roman https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.CommandTaskRunner

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.